# Find similar items in PHP object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've been trying and trying on this and can't seem to work it out on my own.

So could someone please show me the direction I want to take with this?

I want to be able to implode the object items which contain the `string` - `grade_id`.

I've tried getting them all by using `array_filter()` etc. However seems to not return back the right values.

`array_keys()` doesn't bring anything back either to try and match array_keys with a `preg_match`.

I'm just looking for some guidance for this, you don't have to give me a full answered answer, just a point in the right direction.

```
meeting Object
(    
    [errors] => 0
    [id] => 1
    [school_id] => 1
    [staff_id] => 2
    [grade_id] => 85
    [grade_id_2] => 0
    [grade_id_3] => 0
    [grade_id_4] => 0
    [grade_id_5] => 0
    [grade_id_6] => 0
    [grade_id_7] => 0
    [grade_id_8] => 0
    [grade_id_9] => 0
    [grade_id_10] => 0
    [inserted] => 2018-02-19 11:46:13
    [updated] => 2018-02-19 12:00:31
)
```

Result i'm looking for is: (I'm wanting to find a way without using a loop "If possible")

```
$grade_ids = "85";
```

Comment: Why  `85, 0`? Should there not be a lot more zeroes there?

Comment: Now is it an object, or is it an array? Using array functions on objects won’t get you very far ... you would have to convert/cast your object to an array first.

Comment: @ildflue please read my `updated` result part of question

Comment: @CBroe - Is there any `Object filters` similar to the `array_filter`?

Comment: @Chris Beckett you added it afterwards. I should have waited for a while before commented.

Comment: Methods for reading the structure of an object treat private and protected  properties differently from public properties depending on whether they are invoked inside or outside the object. You might try `$arr=json_deconde(json_encode($obj, true));` then apply Alexey's answer.

Comment: If you have the option to re-structure the object so that you have an array of `grade_id`s rather than the clumsy numbered properties, then it would be as simple as using `array_unique()`. This is a clear demonstration of why its important to think about data structures. Refactoring to make this change would probably be a good idea anyway, because you're likely to come up against other reasons in the future why it's better to have it as an array. Make the change now, and save yourself from writing lots of kludges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you convert your object into array:

```
$array = (array)$object;

/* find keys in array that contain 'grade_id' */
$keys = preg_grep('/grade_id/', array_keys($array));

/* discard other array elements */
$filtered = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));

$result = implode(',', $filtered);
```

Comment: This brings back the array key names, doesn't actually give me the array values. Is there a way of returning the values for the keys?

Comment: I have tested this on `stdClass` Think It should return values. https://eval.in/958904

Comment: My bad, I missed out the $filtered part ahah :P

Comment: Is there a way of removing the values from this which is equal to 0?

Comment: Actually i've done it - i've just done the following `$filtered = array_values(array_filter($filtered));`

Comment: Cool. `array_values` is unneeded i think, just `array_filter` is enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), I try like this code:

```
$var = array('meeting'=> array("errors" => 0,
    "id" => 1,
    "school_id" => 1,
    "staff_id" => 2,
    "grade_id" => 85,
    "grade_id_2" => 0,
    "grade_id_3" => 0,
    "grade_id_4" => 0,
    "grade_id_5" => 0,
    "grade_id_6" => 0,
    "grade_id_7" => 0,
    "grade_id_8" => 0,
    "grade_id_9" => 0,
    "grade_id_10" => 0,
    "inserted" => "2018-02-19 11:46:13",
    "updated" => "2018-02-19 12:00:31"));
$uniques = array();

array_walk_recursive($var, function($val, $key) use (&$uniques){
    $i=2;
    if($key == 'grade_id') {
        $uniques[] = $val;
    } if($key == 'grade_id_'.$i) {
        $uniques[] = $val;
    } 
    $i++;
});

$uniques = array_unique($uniques);
print_r($uniques);
```

and output is:

```
Array ( [0] => 85 [1] => 0 )
```